# Calculating LDO thermal requirements

Tags: thermal, ldo

I've got a 5V supply, which I need to pass through an LDO to get 3.3V. The max current that the I need the LDO to support is 1A (at 3.3V). I'm looking at the [TI LM3940](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3940.pdf). Using the DDPAK/TO-263 package, I can see that the *junction-to-ambient thermal resistance*, \$R _{\theta JA}\$, is \$ 40.9^oC \$.

Further down in the datasheet we have the following image:

[image]

There's also the following equations:
$$ I_{IN} = I_{OUT} + I_G$$
$$ P_D = (V_{IN} - V_{OUT})I_{OUT} + (V_{IN})I_G$$

We're told that \$T_R (max) = T_J (max) - T_A (max)\$ (max allowable temperature rise is equal to maximum allowable junction temperature minus maximum ambient temperature).

We can calculate the maximum allowable value for \$R_{\theta (JA)}\$:
$$R_{\theta (JA)} = \frac{T_R (max)}{P_D} $$
As long as \$R_{\theta (JA)}\$ is \$\geqslant 40.9^oC W^{-1}\$, then there's no need for a heatsink.

If we assume that \$T_A (max) = 25^o C\$ and we're told \$T_J (max) = 125^o C\$ we calculate that \$T_R (max) = 100^o C\$

Planning for worst case conditions, let us say that (values from datasheet) \$I_{out} = 1A, V_{in} = 5.5V, V_{out} = 3.13V\$. The bit I'm stuck on is \$I_G\$. Is that the quiescent current? The value of which, for worst case, would be \$250mA\$?

I calculate:

$$R_{\theta (JA)} = \frac{T_R (max)}{P_D} = \frac{100}{3.745} = 26.7^oC $$
\$26.7^oC W^{-1} \leqslant 40.9^oC W^{-1} \therefore \$ a heatsink is required.

Is my understanding correct and calculation correct?

Comment: you got something wrong in your units: a thermal resistance has unit Kelvin/W or °C/W, not °C alone.

Comment: That was just a mistake in my annotation. All values should still be the same.

Comment: Unless I missed something, your understanding is good. But in practice, don't worry too much about the exact figures and just provide more cooling than necessary. Lower operating temperature (unless going below freezing point) is better for a circuit's lifetime.

Comment: Everything you have done looks fine to me. Your assumption about \$I_G = I_Q\$ is correct. I am surprised at the specifications for \$I_Q\$...it seems very, very high to me.

Comment: I've assumed the very worst case for \$I_Q\$. Per the datasheet that value is for \$V_{IN} = 5 V, I_{OUT} = 1 A\$ and \$–40°C ≤ TJ ≤ 125°C\$